# Unable to get connect with bluetooth in sim800

Tags: bluetooth, gsm

I have Sim800 modem and trying to get connected with the bluetooth of the module but when I send command AT+BTPOWER=1 it returns error so I am unable to get connected.
anyone can help in this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your version of Sim800 can be without supporting BT by hardware
2. If your module has hardware support, try to update firmware
3. Try command `BT+STATUS?` probably BT module already powered on

Comment: Sim800 supports Bluetooth but BT+STATUS? returns ERROR.I think I need to update firmware with bluetooth support but that is not available for download on official website.Can you suggest a link?

Comment: I have found the fimware http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/Gboard_800 here.But will it supported on sim800?

Answer (score 0):

Came late to discussion but I must say that you have to turn it off before turning it on. If you try just setting BTPOWER=1 it'll return ERROR, at least for me.

```
AT+BTPOWER=1
ERROR
```

If I set it to 0 before setting to 1 I have success.

```
AT+BTPOWER=0
OK
AT+BTPOWER=1
OK
```